# Getting a percent for one value in a column list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a solution to give me the percent of only one value (nr '1') in a column list. The list contains 3 numbers: 1,2 and 3. 7200 rows.

The code below gives me back the full numbers

`Clouds = df['CloudC'].value_counts(normalize=True).round(decimals=4)*100`

```
3    55.60
1    32.99
2    11.42
Name: CloudC, dtype: float64
```

If possible in one code: The 3 numbers in percent in this order: 1,2,3 including ',' in between

example: `32.99,11.42,55.60`

If not possible, then the code for each value (1,2,3) seperated. But i only need the percent, not the name of the value as output.

example: `32.99 (from value 1)`

Thanks.

UPDATE: The 3 options worked very well. 
How can i let the command line always look for number 1, 2 and 3. I forget this to mention because i was working with a document that for the moment all showed 1, 2, and 3 in the column. But i want the program to look for 1,2,3 all the time, and if a value is not founded, it displays for instance: `0.00, 0.00, 100`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you.The 3 solutions worked. Now is there also a possibility to get always the readings, also if it is 0% for number 1 and 2 for instance. How can i let the command line always look for number 1, 2 and 3. I forget this to mention because i was working with a document that for the moment all showed 1 2 and 3. But i want the program to look for 1,2 and 3, and if it is not founded, is still read: 0%,0%,100%. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) with convert values to strings by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then use `join`:

```
print (', '.join(Clouds.sort_index().astype(str)))
32.99, 11.42, 55.6
```

Another solution, thanks @Vishnudev:

```
print (Clouds.sort_index().astype(str).str.cat(sep=', '))
32.99, 11.42, 55.6
```

If need list:

```
print (Clouds.sort_index().tolist())
[32.99, 11.42, 55.6]
```

Comment: `Clouds.sort_index().astype(str).str.cat(sep=', ')` ? @jezrael

Comment: Using this code now, i notice one problem:
First i use this code:
`Clouds = df['C'].value_counts(normalize=True).round(decimals=4)*100`
Then to print it to a file: 
`+str(','.join(Clouds.reindex([1,2,3], fill_value=0).astype(str)))`

This works great, giving me most of the time accuracy to 2 decimals after the comma. But sometimes it fails and gives me a lot more decimals after the comma. For instance 20.416999999999998.
Is there a way i can solve this?